# Alinhamento vertical Flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Não consigo alinhar os blocos verticalmente depois que é quebrado a linha, ficam muito afastados:

```html
<style>
 body{
  background:black;
 }
.flex-start {
 align-self:flex-start;
}
.wrap {
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container {
 background:white;
 max-width: 360px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display:flex;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 height:105px;
}
.item {
 flex: 1;
 margin: 5px;
 background: tomato;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
</style>

<section class="container wrap">
 <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
 <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
    <div class="item flex-start">bloco<br><br></div>
    <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
    <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
    <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
    <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
    <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
    <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
</section>
```

Quero muito aproximar essa distância vertical entre 
o bloco da linha anterior com o bloco da linha posterior.
Pretendo deixá-los próximos mesmo contendo algum bloco de
tamanho diferente.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/ leia que vai te interessa, aqui tem o plugin https://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Como você mesmo disse a necessidade, o que voce pode fazer é, ao inves de usar a tag `<br>` para separar os blocos, voce pode colocar a quantidade de itens necessarias dentro de cada bloco de itens, onde estes vão ter a funcionalidade do `justify-content` que os deixarão separados de forma identica e automatica. Se voce abrir o inspecionar elemento do seu navegador, vai ver que o espaço entre um bloco e outro, não contém margin, e sim provém de seu tamanho. Se quiser aproxima-los bastante, use de margin negativa ( mas não recomendado ), pois essa questão automática, provém da melhor experiencia de uso e visibilidade para o usuário.

```
<style>
    body {
        background: black;
    }

    .flex-start {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .container {
        background: white;
        max-width: 360px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        height: 105px;
    }


    .wrap {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .item {
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0 5px;
        background: tomato;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .wrap-item {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
</style>

<section class="container wrap">
    <div class="wrap-item">
        <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
        <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
        <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
        <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
    </div>


    <div class="wrap-item">
        <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
        <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
        <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
        <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: @wDrik eu coloquei o <br> p/ demonstrar visto que cada bloco terá um conteúdo diferente resultando um tamanho diferente. Quero proximidade entre todos blocos

Comment: Se é o caso voce pode fazer de maneira diferente, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, eu já tinha feito desse jeito e o que eu tento é deixar os blocos próximos de todos os lados. Msm centrado é visível espaçamento sobrando.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, pelo que entendi é isso que vc precisa?! `align-items: stretch;` em `.flex-start`

```css
body{
  background:black;
}
.flex-start {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container {
  background:white;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:flex;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height:105px;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<section class="container wrap">
  <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
  <div class="item flex-start">bloco<br><br></div>
  <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
  <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
  <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
  <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
  <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
  <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
  <div class="item flex-start">bloco</div>
</section>
```